# Unable to go in "else" block of If Else condition in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

On running the below code, I am getting to the `else` block of String comparison section.

But unable to get into the `else` block of Boolean comparison section.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters{
    
        string(
                name: "s_Project_Branch_Name", defaultValue: "master",
                description: "Enter Brnach Name")
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            input {
                message "Proceed to Prod Deployment with ${params.s_Project_Branch_Name} branch?"
                ok "Yes"
                parameters {
                    string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
                    booleanParam(name: "TOGGLE", defaultValue: false, description: "Check this box to Proceed.")
                }
            }
            steps {
                // echo "Hello, ${PERSON}, nice to meet you."
               
                script{
                    echo 'String'
                    if ("${PERSON}" == "${params.s_Project_Branch_Name}") {
                        echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
                    } else {
                        echo 'I execute elsewhere'
                        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                    }
                }


                script{
                    echo 'Boolean'
                    echo "${TOGGLE}"
                    if ("${TOGGLE}") {
                        echo 'I only execute if boolean true'
                    } else {
                        error('I only execute if boolean false')
                        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do String interpolation `"${TOGGLE}"` you will be getting a String, not a Boolean. If you want to get the Boolean value you can directly access the variable by doing `params.TOGGLE`. So change the condition like below.

```
if (params.TOGGLE) {
    echo 'I only execute if boolean true'
} else {
    error('I only execute if boolean false')
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
}
```

OR

```
if ("${TOGGLE}" == "true") {
    echo 'I only execute if boolean true'
} else {
    error('I only execute if boolean false')
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks.
Additionally, can you tell me about a way I can check the data type of any variable ?

Comment: @AyushAdarsh easiest way is to check the Class. `echo "${params.TOGGLE.getClass()}"`